# What is 'X-SCHEMA' in ApacheDS schema?

Tags: ldap, openldap, apacheds

We are implementing LDAP client for ApacheDS. As part of implementation we are retrieving and parsing schema. As part of `objectClasses` schema we have `X-SCHEMA`. If we consider `pwcPolicy` object it has definition like `( 1.3.6.1.4.1.42.2.27.8.2.1 NAME 'pwdPolicy' DESC 'class to hold the PasswordPolicy parameters' SUP top AUXILIARY MUST pwdAttribute MAY ( pwdMinAge $ pwdMaxAge $ pwdInHistory $ pwdCheckQuality $ pwdMinLength $ pwdMaxLength $ pwdExpireWarning $ pwdGraceAuthNLimit $ pwdGraceExpire $ pwdLockout $ pwdLockoutDuration $ pwdMaxFailure $ pwdFailureCountInterval $ pwdMustChange $ pwdAllowUserChange $ pwdSafeModify $ pwdMinDelay $ pwdMaxDelay $ pwdMaxIdle ) X-SCHEMA 'pwdpolicy' )`which has `X-SCHEMA` with value as `pwdpolicy`.

Could anyone provide inputs on what is `X-SCHEMA` and how it can be used in the LDAP client implementation.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Per LDAP RFCs, the objectClasses syntax is extensible, and the policy is to identify extensions with the X- prefix.
The X-SCHEMA is a tag to be able to group objectClass and attributes that are part of the same schema origin.

OpenDJ (and ForgeRock Directory Services) use another extension (for the same schema):  X-ORIGIN 'draft-behera-ldap-password-policy'